# Bounding a functional $|T(g)| \leq C ||g - g_0||^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, statistics

For convergence results I usually see that if we have a sequence of real-valued functions $g_n$, a real-valued function $g_0$, and some distribution $F$ such that $||g_n-g_0||^2 = \int |g_n(x) - g_0(x)|^2 F(dx) \to 0$, the following is assumed about a functional $T(\cdot)$: $|T(g)| \leq C||g - g_0||^2$ for all $g$ (in some space $\mathcal{G}$) with $||g-g_0||$ small enough. My question regards rigorously proving this assumption holds (or does not hold) for a series of examples. First the simplest example:
$$
T(g) = \int (g(x) - g_0(x)) F(dx)
$$
The second example:
$$
T(g) = \int (|g(x)| - |g_0(x)|)F(dx)
$$
And the third example:
$$
T(g) = \int [1(g(x)>0) - 1(g_0(x)>0)] F(dx) 
$$
where $1(.)$ is $1$ if the condition inside is true and zero otherwise. Any answer on any of the examples is appreciated, also any explanation about what properties of $T(g)$, $g$ or $F$ make the assumption hold or not hold.